# How to eliminate the duplication in these 2 interfaces caused by using struct as parameter?

Tags: c#

I have 2 C# interfaces like this:

```
public interface IEvernoteJobListener
{
    void CopyS3File(S3Location src, EvernoteLocation des, Action<Exception> complete);
}

public interface ICopyJobListener
{
    void CopyS3File(S3Location src, S3Location des, Action<Exception> complete);
}
```

You can see that they are almost identical besides their second parameter, which makes the implementation nearly identical.  What stops me from merge them into a single interface is that EvernoteLocation and S3Location are structs, so I can't make them inherit from the same parent and thus eliminate the difference between them and only keep one interface and one method.

What are the possible solutions to eliminate the duplication of the interface?

Edit:

The code of implementation might help clarify the question:

```
    public void CopyS3File (S3Location src, EvernoteLocation des, Action<Exception> complete)
    {
        reader.ReadS3ToFile(src, (file, readExc) => {
            if(readExc != null)
            {
                complete(readExc);
                return;
            }

           // This is a Evernote writer.
            writer.WriteFromFile(file, des, writeExc => {
                complete(writeExc);
            });
        });
    }


    public void CopyS3File (S3Location src, S3Location des, Action<Exception> complete)
    {
        reader.ReadS3ToFile(src, (file, readExc) => {
            if(readExc != null)
            {
                complete(readExc);
                return;
            }

               // This is a S3 writer.
            writer.WriteFromFile(file, des, writeExc => {
                complete(writeExc);
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: Even if they were classes rather than structs, and you could inherit from a common base, could you really have just a single interface? Do your implementations of the two interfaces not behave differently?

Comment: I added the code of implementation.  They were struct cos they don't really contains any behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the interface generic.

```
public interface IJobListener<TDes>
{
    void CopyS3File(S3Location src, TDes des, Action<Exception> complete);
}
```

But I don't know how that helps with your implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Why not implement an interface on both structs and use that as input parameter?

```
public struct S3Location : ICanHasInterface
{
    //...
}

public struct EvernoteLocation : ICanHasInterface
{
    //...
}

public interface ICopyJobListener
{
    void CopyS3File(S3Location src, ICanHasInterface des, Action<Exception> complete);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use generic type parameter:

```
interface IJobLIstener<T>
{
  void CopyS3File(S3Location src, T des, Action<Exception> complete)
}

public interface IEvernoteJobListener: IJobLIstener<EvernoteLocation>
{
}

public interface ICopyJobListener: IJobLIstener<S3Location>
{
}
```

BTW,

if S3Location encapsulates more than 2-3 primitive type values I would recommend to make it `class` rather than `structure`

Comment: I'll grant you that, the generic version does stress where there is commonality, and where there is specialisation.

Comment: Now I got what are you mean... Just found that another SO member has edited my post after I've accientally post not finished answer

Comment: @David Heffernan: sorry but I do not get what are you mean in the last comment

Comment: I'm agreeing that whilst the code is longer, it is clearer. From the perspective of the question though, there still need to be two implementations.

Comment: Why do you think struct with more than 2 or 3 parameters should be class?

Comment: @ablmf: As far as I remember common recommendation is to introduce class when size of struct is more than 16 bytes